# Getting error on C++ & OpenCV: "malloc"

Tags: c++, opencv, malloc

I'm taking some images and cutting them into dimension `dimensionImage`x `dimensionImage` which is 256x256 as:

```
Mat getKdimensionImage(String file, int dimension) {

    Mat result = Mat::zeros(dimension, dimension, CV_8U);

    Mat currentImage = imread(file, CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE);

    for (int i = 0; i < dimension; i++) {
         for (int j = 0; j < dimension; j++) {
            result.at<int>(i,j) = currentImage.at<int>(i,j);
         }
    }

return result;
}
```

then, on my **main** I'm loading 2 images:

```
Mat face1 = getKdimensionImage(path + "FACE/face1.jpg", dimensionImage);
Mat face2 = getKdimensionImage(path + "FACE/face2.jpg", dimensionImage);
```

but when I start loading face2 I get:

> OpenCVtry(18811,0x7fff73568310) malloc: *** error for object 0x10381d608: incorrect checksum for freed object - object was probably modified after being freed.
>   *** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug

I'm sorry, I'm Java developer and this is kind of burning my brain...

what could be my problem ?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Should you use CV_8UC1 rather than just CV_8U?

Comment: Yes!, please could you post it as answer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you have a buffer overflow here, due to wrong type access:

```
result.at<int>(i,j) = currentImage.at<int>(i,j);
```

both Mat's are uchar, not int so it has to be:

```
result.at<uchar>(i,j) = currentImage.at<uchar>(i,j);
```

also, it might be a good idea, to run this in debug mode, your code would have thrown a proper exception.

Comment: Yeah... I controlled again...
The first time worked with CV_8UC1 because of that I said @Octopus to answer... but you are right! thank you

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure OpenCV is interpretting CV_8U correctly. I believe you want CV_8UC1.